# A man was born in 1881 and died in 1883, yet he was 90. How?

Tags: lateral-thinking

A man was born in 1881 and died in 1883, yet he was 90. How it is possible?

Comment: Voting to reopen - though the statement of the question is similar, the answer is completely different, so I don't believe it's a duplicate.

Comment: I'd opine it should remain closed - it's a bit of a [chestnut](https://www.quora.com/How-come-a-man-was-born-in-1881-and-died-in-1883-yet-he-was-90) which uses arguments similar to the original question. Also, the question states _a man_ (i.e. adult) so the unit of time used in the answer seems flawed. @boboquack

Comment: I agree it's not an exact duplicate, but nothing here invalidates the other question's answers. If we reopened this, it would have to be closed as too broad, as clearly there are several possible answers.

Comment: @bobo Agreed: this is a completely different puzzle.

Comment: The right thing to do obviously is to roll back the erroneous edit, instead of wringing your collective hands to no good purpose. And then vote to reopen it, as it was not a duplicate. Both of which have now been done. I'm not sure this is a *puzzle* - and, at best, it's one of those "brain teasers" that are usually way too broad for their own good - so it might be close-worthy anyway ... but not as a duplicate.  @MeaCulpaNay please be careful with edits, and if (as here) an edit turns out to be problematic, don't leave the broken edit in place.

Comment: @James If you found this puzzle from another source, please [provide attribution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's that:

> He was 90 weeks old when he died.

Comment: 90 weeks is almost 2 years, so this is likely right

Comment: Am I correct then?

Comment: I dont know, U have to wait for OP to accept your answer

Comment: Erm, can a _man_ really be the age in the answer? The phrase _a man_ implies an adult.

Comment: @Phylyp Someone referring to a 1-year-old as "90" without units to suggest anything other than "years" would probably also refer to that same 1-year-old as a "man".

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/

Answer (score 9):

The man:

> Was born in a hospital room numbered 1881 and died in a one numbered 1883.

Comment: Very creative :)